# pptpd connects but no data

Tags: vpn, pptp, pptpd

I have setup pptp on my vps using this tutorial https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PPTPServer

No issues there. I can connect via mobile device successfully with the username and password I configured but there's no internet on the phone. Skype/Websites/Whatsapp nothing

I tried the suggestions here too [pptpd VPN: No internet access after connecting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/492923/pptpd-vpn-no-internet-access-after-connecting)

I checked many answers but I'm seriously stuck. Any ideas? No idea how to troubleshoot either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved using [Create VPN server using the Ubuntu VPS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/199286/create-vpn-server-using-the-ubuntu-vps)

This is the only line I needed in rc.local

`iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.0.0/24 ! -d 192.168.0.0/24 -j SNAT --to-source XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX` where XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX = the public IP of the VPS